# Twilio destination number parsing

Tags: twilio, sip, voip

Destination number Parsing

Hi All,

I have setup a SIP domain and I'm handling calls over to a Studio flow. I have managed to successfully connect an iPhone app to this. Now I am trying to extract the number dialed in the app but it seems less than straightforward. For example if i dial `01273123123` then the `trigger.call.To` variable contains ``` sip:1273123123@my-sip-domain.sip.region.twilio.com``;transport=UDP ```. I'm writing a Twilio cloud function to try to extract the destination from the SIP URL, but was expecting an easier way to do this.

Any ideas?